# VOLUME data for TradingView

Tags: aggregation, volume

Question about TradingView VOLUME data in TradingView

**QUESTION**
When I add all the intraday volume bars for a ticker in a given then (e.g.TSLA), I do not get the same volume as the daily bar for the same day.

**EXAMPLE**
For example, on the 13th MAR 2023, I downloaded the 5min TradingView data, put in excel and all volume bars add to 14M shares but when I switch to the Daily Timeframe and look at the volume for 13thMAR2023 as 1 bar I see the value 112M.

It is nowhere near close. Can someone show what am I missing?

Thank you!